# Erro no applicationContext-security.xml

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-security

Meu 1º arquivo xml applicationContext-security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<b:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">
<http auto-config="true">

    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="ROLE_ADMINISTRADOR" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/restrito/*" access="ROLE_USUARIO" />
    <form-login login-page="/publico/login.jsf"
        always-use-default-target="true" default-target-url="/restrito/principal.jsf"
        authentication-failure-url="/publico/login.jsf?login_error=1" />
    <logout/>
    <remember-me />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="financeiroDataSource"
            authorities-by-username-query="SELECT u.login, p.permissao 
                                         FROM usuario u, usuario_permissao p 
                                        WHERE u.codigo = p.usuario 
                                          AND u.login = ?"
            users-by-username-query="SELECT login, senha, ativo 
                                   FROM usuario 
                                  WHERE login = ?" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
</b:beans>
```

E tem este outro applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
<bean id="financeiroDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>java:comp/env/jdbc/FinanceiroDB</value>
    </property>
</bean>     
</beans>
```

Todos estão na pasta WEB-INFO.

Es são os erros no log do tomcat:

1º

GRAVE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/security]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml]

2º

set 09, 2014 9:47:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
GRAVE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/security]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml]

Minhas libs:

spring-2.5.6.jar
spring-security-cas-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-openid-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-remoting-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-samples-contacts-3.0.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-security-samples-tutorial-3.0.2.RELEASE-sources.jar

Comment: Parece que o XML de configuração não está no padrão requerido. Dependendo do IDE você pode validar esse XML antes de executar a aplicação. Qual IDE você está usando?

Comment: @Luídne Estou usando o Eclipse

Comment: Poste também seu XML. Vai ajudar muito nesse caso.

Comment: Mudei a descrição do erro e adicionei os meus arquivos. @Luíde

Comment: Que versão do Tomcat e Spring Security você está usando?

Comment: Mais uma coisa, quais as libs você está usando no projeto?

Comment: @Luídne adicionei na descrição as libs que estou usando do spring. E atualizei os dois erros que acontecem ao iniciar o tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

O que está acontecendo é o seguinte, no XML o manipulador do namespace `http://www.springframework.org/schema/security` não está sendo encontrado. Isto porque está faltando uma biblioteca que contém essa classe manipuladora.

E para tal, a biblioteca do framework que está faltando é a: **spring-security-config-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar**
Se você ver os arquivos dentro da pasta `META-INF` deste .jar verá os arquivos que define a classe que tratará esse namespace.

> Portanto, basta adicionar a biblioteca mencionada que o erro não ocorrerá mais. 
>   Porém, é bom adicionar todas as outras bibliotecas do Spring Security no projeto e caso queira reduzir o tamanho do .war vá removendo uma de cada vez para ver quais não são necessárias.

Outras informações:
http://www.baeldung.com/unable-to-locate-spring-namespacehandler-for-xml-schema-namespace